# How can i do another TextInputLayout error state?

Tags: android, xml, angular-material

I use material 3 and have TextInputLayout, but my error state seems like this: [current error state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSezK.png)

But I know that the following state could be used in the design-support-library:
[required error state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NXpM.png)

As far as I know, this library is not supported. So how do I make the required state?

Comment: Answer: you need to apply error to the TextInputLayout, and not to the editText nested in it :)